# Как с помощью javascript удалить ударение?

Tags: javascript

Есть такая строка:

```
Топони́мика
```

Как отсюда с помощью javascript удалить ударение? Возможно ли его убрать с помощью регулярных выражений?

Answer (score 7):

Знак ударения `◌́` это юникод-символ `U+0301`.
Так что его можно удалить так:

```js
console.log("Топони́мика".replace(/\u0301/g, ""))
```